# python interfaces with vissim COM

Tags: python, com

I use python to interface with Vissim COM, i can open the vissim, load road network and change network file position, but when I want to add the new links to network, there is something wrong.  It shows ' File "c:\software\python\install\lib\site packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self.*username*, attr))'

my code is attached

```
import win32com.client as com
Vissim = com.Dispatch("Vissim.Vissim")
Vissim.LoadNet(r'C:\Users\hanxintong\Desktop\Railroad\albina.inp')
Vissim.SaveNetAs(r'C:\Users\hanxintong\Desktop\Railroad\practice.inp') 
Vissim.Simulation.RunContinuous()
Vissim.Net.Links.Addlink(42, 'LineString(0 30, 200 200)', [3.5, 3.5])
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple typo in your code: instead of "Addlink" you ashould write "AddLink" with capital L.